# Set equal bin widths for histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I need 4 histograms for 4 different organisms, data is extremely diverse, but the limits of the axes and (that's MORE important) the widths of ALL bins should be equal in each and every plot. 
I have this code

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(16, 10))
colors = ['tab:red', 'tab:blue', 'tab:green', 'tab:pink']

for i, (ax, Organism) in enumerate(zip(axes.flatten(), data.Organism.unique())):
    x = data.loc[data.Organism == Organism, 'Protein Length']
    ax.hist(x, density=True, label=str(Organism), color=colors[i], alpha=0.5, rwidth=0.5, bins = 30)
    ax.set_xscale("log")
    ax.set_xlim([min(data["Protein Length"]), max(data["Protein Length"])])
```

What else should I specify  to get EQUAL bin widths everywhere?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First you can make your life easier and use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html). It's built on top of `matplotlib`. Dealing with `matplotlib` can be a bit of a pain - lot of code and it's not stateless.

If you want kickass plots, with a bit more coding, go [plotly](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py).

You can always calculate your histogram [separately](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the number of bins, you can set all the bins themselves:

```
ax.hist(x, density=True, label=str(Organism), color=colors[i],
           alpha=0.5, rwidth=0.5, bins=np.linspace(first_bin, last_bin, 30))
```

where `start_bin` and `last_bin` are the starting point and the end point of the histogram.